# How to Make a Bit Copy of my Internal HD to an Extneral HD?

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clone a hard drive to an image that I can open later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11067/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-to-an-image-that-i-can-open-later)

This question stemed from my other [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/231889/23251):

How do I make a bit copy of my internal hard drive to an external hard drive and check the disk for errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your external harddrive is larger than your internal i would use

`sudo ddrescue /dev/sda /dev/sdb logfile`

note: sda is your source disk sdb is your destination drive (external).
 this will also overwrite any data on your external drive

you can install ddrescue via `sudo apt-get install ddrescue`

i prefer ddrescue over normal dd becasue it gives you a nice progress bar and it will log i/o errors

Answer (score 2):

I regularly make complete hardrive copies using Clonezilla.

> Clonezilla, based on DRBL, Partclone and udpcast, allows you to do bare metal backup and recovery.

I recommend downloading the live version and boot your computer from it then you can make a complete copy of the harddrive to and external drive or network drive. Clonezilla will also run checks if you wish during and after creating the copy.

References:

[Clonezilla Website](http://clonezilla.org/)